# Process data from char array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a little problem,

I have a char array like this:

`char buff[256] = { "2 22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"};`

and what I need to do is:

- if 1st number in buff is bigger than 5 I need to sort this numbers ASC
- if 1st number in buff is smaller than 5 I need to sort this numbers DESC

in this example the 1st number is 2, so I need to sort this array DESC

I want to create an int array and copy numbers from char buff to int array but I can't figure out how to do this.

Sorting this data in int array will be easy.

I have tried smth like this:

```
    int array[256];
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
        array[i] = atoi(&buff2[i]);
```

and the result is not good

```
array[0]: 2
array[1]: 22
array[2]: 22
array[3]: 2
array[4]: 3
array[5]: 3
array[6]: 14
array[7]: 14
array[8]: 4
array[9]: 5
array[10]: 5
array[11]: 8
array[12]: 8
array[13]: 23
array[14]: 23
array[15]: 3
array[16]: 45
array[17]: 45
array[18]: 5
array[19]: 2
array[20]: 2
array[21]: 7
array[22]: 7
array[23]: 88
array[24]: 88
array[25]: 8
```

Comment: you need to use strtok to split the string up delimited by space

Comment: " want to create an int array and copy numbers from char buff to int array" why are you not using a `int` array in the first place?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: I am not even sure the declaration is correct

Comment: "*I have tried smth like this:*" Please post exact verbatim code the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Athough I can see the problem. First you convert `"2 22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"` and then you convert `" 22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"` and then you convert `"22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"`and then you convert `"2 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"` and then you convert `" 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"` and so on.

Comment: if you read `man atoi` (as opposed to hoping it does what you want) you will see exactly why you are getting the results you are getting. use strtok or sscanf

Comment: I cannot find identifier `smth` in the provided code.

Comment: @user4581301 "smth" ==> "something".

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

For a 'C' answer, I would use `strtol`, because it tells you where the parsed number ends in the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {
    char buff[] = "2 22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88";
    char* p=buff;
    for(;;) {
        char* ep;  // end pointer
        int n = strtol(p, &ep, 0);
        // if ep == p, no parsing took place
        if(p != ep) {
            // parsing succeeded
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
        if(!*ep) break;  // check if we hit the end of the string
        p = ep + 1;      // advance to the next character
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
2
22
3
14
5
8
23
45
2
7
88
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++, you may want to convert the text to a `std::istringstream` then treat as an input stream:

```
const char buff[] = { "2 22 3 14 5 8 23 45 2 7 88"};
const std::string text(buff);
std::vector<int> database;
std::istringstream  buf_stream(text);
int value;
while (buf_stream >> value)
{
    database.push_back(value);
}
```

For ascending and descending sorting, you can write comparison functions and pass them to `std::sort`.